# Output random item from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function() {
        var optionsArray = $(".inputID").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");

        var randomOutput = optionsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*optionsArray.length)];

        console.log(randomOutput);

    });
```

What I'm trying to do upon clicking the button (.submit_button) is for it to take the user entered data (they are inputs with the class .inputID), store them in an array (which i have done and it works) and then console.log (at least for now while I'm testing) one of the inputs at random. What it currently does is just console.logs a single character instead of a whole item from the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't want to use `.join()`, which gives a string instead of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `join`

```
    var optionsArray = $(".inputID").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
```

`join()` method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the single character is because a String is effectively an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a `join`. So optionsArray is one single string, not an array anyomore. So `optionsArray[<anything>]` is basically a character.

Remove the `join(",")` part and it'll work.